# Inhomogeneous ODE where the RHS is $x\sin(x)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I was trying to solve $\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}+y=x\sin(x)$ by following the standard procedure. Whilst I got the complementary function to be $y=A\cos(x)+B\sin(x)$, I am stuck in trying to figure out what particular integral I should try. Can someone please help?

Comment: Do you know about how to rewrite the system as a first order differential equation in matrix form?

Comment: take a look here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variation_of_parameters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have, $\frac{d^2y}{dx^2} + y = xsinx$

or, $(D^2 + 1)y = xsinx$

$PI = \frac{1}{D^2 + 1}xsinx = I.P \ of \frac{1}{D^2 + 1}xe^{ix}$

Isolating $e^{ix}$ and replacing $D$ by $D + i$

[ ***IP for imaginary part***]

$PI = \ IP \ of\  e^{ix} \frac{1}{(D+i)^2 + 1}x =\ IP \ of \ e^{ix} \frac{1}{(D^2 + 2iD - 1 + 1)}x \ = \ IP \ of\  e^{ix} \frac{1}{2Di}.\frac{1}{1 + \frac{D}{2i}} x$

Using the binomial expansion, $\frac{1}{x+1} = 1-x+x^2.... \ for \ |x|<1$

and
 $D(x) = \frac{d}{dx} x = 1 \ , D^2(x) = D^3(x) = ... = 0$

$PI = \ IP \ of\  e^{ix} \frac{1}{2Di}.(1- \frac{D}{2i} + (\frac{D}{2i})^2...) x$

$PI = \ IP \ of\  e^{ix} \frac{1}{2Di}.(x - \frac{1}{2i})  = \ IP \ of\  e^{ix} \frac{1}{2i}.\int(x - \frac{1}{2i}) dx $

$PI =  \ IP \ of\  e^{ix} \frac{1}{2i}.(\frac{x^2}{2} - \frac{x}{2i}) = \ IP \ of\  e^{ix}(\frac{x^2}{4i} + \frac{x}{4}) = IP \ of \ (cosx + isinx)(\frac{x^2}{4i} + \frac{x}{4})$

$PI = IP \ of \ (\frac{-ix^2cosx}{4} + \frac{xcosx}{4} + \frac{x^2sinx}{4} + \frac{ixsinx}{4})  $

$PI = \frac{xsinx}{4} - \frac{x^2cosx}{4}$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

The derivative of a polynomial times sine/cosine is also a polynomial times sin/cosine. Try and guess what degree this polynomial should have.

Answer (score 1):

The given differential equation is

$y'' + y = x \sin\ x$
$ \implies (D^2 + 1)y=x \sin x$

where $D \equiv \frac{d}{dx} $

I think you have an idea about how to find the Complementary Function (i.e., C.F.), (for your case, which is nothing but the solution of the homogeneous differential equation $y'' + y =0$).

Here C.F. is $c_1 \cos x+c_2 \sin x$.

Now for the Particular Integral (i.e., P.I.) there are some general rules

> $1.$ $\frac{1}{D + a} \phi (x) = e^{-ax}\int e^{ax}\phi(x)$
>
> $2.$ $\frac{1}{f(D)} e^{ax} \phi(x) = e^{ax}\frac{1}{f(D+a)} \phi(x)$
>
> $3.$ $\frac{1}{f(D)} x^{n} \sin ax  = $Imaginary part of $e^{iax}\frac{1}{f(D+ia)} x^n$
>
> $4.$ $\frac{1}{f(D)} x^{n} \cos ax  = $Real part of $e^{iax}\frac{1}{f(D+ia)} x^n$
>
> $5.$ $\frac{1}{f(D)} x^{n} (\cos ax + i\sin ax)  = \frac{1}{f(D)} x^n e^{iax}=e^{iax}\frac{1}{f(D+ia)} x^n$

So for your problem, P.I. is $\frac{1}{D^2 +1}  (x\sin x)$

$= $ Imaginary part of $e^{ix}\frac{1}{(D+i)^2 + 1} x$

$=$ Imaginary part of $e^{ix}\frac{1}{D^2 + 2iD} x$

$=$ Imaginary part of $e^{ix}\frac{1}{2iD(1- \frac{Di}{2} )} x$

$=$ Imaginary part of $e^{ix}\frac{1}{2iD} (1 +\frac{Di}{2}+\frac{D^2i^2}{4}+ . . .  )  x $

$=$ Imaginary part of $\frac{1}{2}e^{ix}(\frac{1}{iD}+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{Di}{4}+ . . .) x$

$=$ Imaginary part of $\frac{1}{2} (\cos x +i \sin x)(\frac{-ix^2}{2}+\frac{x}{2}+\frac{i}{4}+ . . .)$

$=\frac{1}{2} \{\frac{x\sin x}{2}+\frac{1-2x^2}{4}\cos x\}$

$=\{\frac{x\sin x}{4}+\frac{1-2x^2}{8}\cos x\}$

Hence the general solution is

$y=$ C.F. $+$ P.I.

$ = c_1 \cos x+c_2 \sin x+\frac{x\sin x}{4}+\frac{1-2x^2}{8}\cos x$

$= A \cos x+B \sin x+\frac{x\sin x}{4}$,

where $A$ and $B$ are functions of $x$.

Answer (score 0):

The solution of the inhomogeneous equation is $$y(x)=A\sin(x)+B\cos(x)$$.For a particular equation make the ansatz $$y_P=Cx^2\cos(x)+Dx\sin(x)$$